# Why can't I send too many request's to google maps API, using PHP curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with curl php script, the script breaks if I send more than 5 requests.

I tried to execute the script from server side, since I thought it is a internet connection problem, but it didn't work.

The script pulls out information from my database and searches the google maps for the exact address.

Sometimes it takes for 2500 requests sometimes 100, it's random.
If I use a limit of 5 requests and 1 as array chunk, works like a charm, no errors.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

//includes
include_once("inc_dbcon.php");

//get data from db
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `geo` where `state` = "FL" ORDER BY rand() limit 0,5000');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//simplified request just to test if it works...
$competeRequests[] = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0519,-118.243" ;

}


$curlRequest = array();

foreach (array_chunk($competeRequests, 1000) as $requests) {
$results = multiRequest($requests);

$curlRequest = array_merge($curlRequest, $results);

}

$j = 0;
foreach ($curlRequest as $json){
$j++;
$json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$newlat = $json_output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$newlong = $json_output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
$address=$json_output['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
$zip = explode(",", $address);
$state_zip = explode(" ", trim($zip[2]));
$the_zip =$state_zip[1];
if($newlat) {

    $out = "$the_zip, $newlat, $newlong ";
    //show output
    echo $out . "<br/>";

}
}


function multiRequest($data) {
// array of curl handles
$curly = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();

// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// loop through $data and create curl handles
// then add them to the multi-handle
foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

$curly[$id] = curl_init();

$url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// post?
if (is_array($d)) {
  if (!empty($d['post'])) {
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
    }
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
}

// execute the handles
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);

// get content and remove handles
foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
$result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

// all done
curl_multi_close($mh);

return $result;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are breaking usage limits on google maps. The actual number seems to be 10 per second.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/quota

Here is a possible solution:

```
<?php

//includes
include_once("inc_dbcon.php");

//get data from db
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `geo` where `state` = "FL" ORDER BY rand() limit 0,20');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//simplified request just to test if it works...
$competeRequests[] = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0519,-118.243" ;

}


$curlRequest = array();

foreach (array_chunk($competeRequests, 10) as $requests) {
$results = multiRequest($requests);

$curlRequest = array_merge($curlRequest, $results);
sleep(1);
}

$j = 0;
foreach ($curlRequest as $json){
$j++;
$json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$newlat = $json_output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$newlong = $json_output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
$address=$json_output['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
$zip = explode(",", $address);
$state_zip = explode(" ", trim($zip[2]));
$the_zip =$state_zip[1];
if($newlat) {

    $out = "$the_zip, $newlat, $newlong ";
    //show output
    echo $out . "<br/>";

}
}


function multiRequest($data) {
// array of curl handles
$curly = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();

// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// loop through $data and create curl handles
// then add them to the multi-handle
foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

$curly[$id] = curl_init();

$url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// post?
if (is_array($d)) {
  if (!empty($d['post'])) {
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
    }
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
}

// execute the handles
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);

// get content and remove handles
foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
$result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
}

// all done
curl_multi_close($mh);

return $result;

}

?>
```

Comment: i saw that, and that's seems to be the problem if nothing is wrong with my code. how can i pause the script after each 10 requests?

Comment: PHP provides you with the sleep function(), you probably want to split the array into pieces of 10 and then stick it in an array, I'm thinking of how right now.

Comment: @john You can try this implementation :)

Comment: can't get it to work "array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in test.php on line 21" and " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 26". ps: lowered the mysql query limit to 20 and array_chunk to 10, otherwise i think it will take ages to finish looping...

Comment: I thought the solution was too complex, right if you are already using array chuck then just put the sleep to the end of that

Comment: can you be more precise please?

Comment: oh, sorry i already tried that but without luck, it still gives me random errors "Undefined offset: 0 in test.php on line 32" ... ... ... then it returns a few rows of data, again errors and so on. i just tried with 2 sec of sleep but i have to wait until it finishes., i'll get back with an answer once it finishes.

Comment: problem solved, using a 2 sec pause will work just fine, of course the execution time is painful but at least i can get my data up to date.

Comment: Okay that's cool, interesting that 2 seconds work but 1 doesn't

Comment: i think it's because i am trying to use the maximum limit of request per second and the server reaches over_limit. also it's possible that the first chunk with 10 request is not completed by google maps server when the scripts send another one and again it reaches over_limit. anyway the 2 sec delay it's working and will do it's job, slower but without errors. Many thanks mate for pointing in the right direction!